# Download partial content for a file attachment of a message using MicrosoftGraph API

Tags: office365, attachment, microsoft-graph-api

I need to ***partial download*** the file attachments of a message using MicrosoftGraph API.

I'm using the following endpoint to get the attachment

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}`

But the above request only support authorization header as per [this](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get#request-headers) documentation. I tried the Range header but is not working. Is there a way to perform *partial download* of file attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for partial download. Please make a feature request explaining the use case at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

However, $select parameter can be used to get properties other than contentBytes if the aim to reduce the response size.

Comment: Thanks for the response. _$select_ parameter won't be suitable for me. I need to download the content of the attachment as a parallel process for multiple users.